# How to politely tell my personal tutor that I'm going to give her the tutoring fee?

Tags: politeness

What I'm looking for is the most polite way to tell my personal tutor that I'm going to give her money without her feeling that she's selling something and I'm buying it. To put it another way, I'm looking for more polite versions of these:

"Here's the money for this month", "I'll pay you tomorrow"

(I exaggerated the two examples a bit to demonstrate which phrases I'm looking for more clearly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling it a 'fee' instead of 'money' will put emphasis on the teacher-student relationship. After all, it is a remuneration for rights or services that you are offering. This is a common Indian-English usage.

"Here is the fees for the month/week of _____. Thank you".

Comment: how about the future version of that ?? If I tell my PT that I'm giving her the fee next time I see her, I can't say "here is ...".

Comment: "I will be paying my fees on ________".